# How to make Fixed objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 objects left is without Rigidbody and right is with Rigidbody(is Kinematic=false).I can pass through the left one and the right one I can move.How to make in order that the character doesn't pass and move the objects?

Without Rigidbody

[image]

With Rigidbody

[image]

Character

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Person_controller : MonoBehaviour {
    public float rotationPeriod = 0.3f;
    public float sideLength = 1f;

    bool isRotate = false;
    float directionX = 0;
    float directionZ = 0;

    Vector3 startPos;
    float rotationTime = 0;
    float radius;
    Quaternion fromRotation;
    Quaternion toRotation;

    void Start () {
        radius = sideLength * Mathf.Sqrt (2f) / 2f;
    }

    void Update () {
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;

        x = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        if (x == 0) {
            y = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        }


        if ((x != 0 || y != 0) && !isRotate) {
            directionX = y;                                                         
            directionZ = x;                                                             
            startPos = transform.position;                                              
            fromRotation = transform.rotation;                                          
            transform.Rotate (directionZ * 90, 0, directionX * 90,            Space.World);        
            toRotation = transform.rotation;                                            
            transform.rotation = fromRotation;                                          
            rotationTime = 0;       

            isRotate = true;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {

        if (isRotate) {

            rotationTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;                                    
            float ratio = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, rotationTime / rotationPeriod);          


            float thetaRad = Mathf.Lerp(0, Mathf.PI / 2f, ratio);                   
            float distanceX = (-directionX * radius * (Mathf.Cos (45f *    Mathf.Deg2Rad) - Mathf.Cos (45f * Mathf.Deg2Rad + thetaRad)))*sideLength;   
            float distanceY = radius * (Mathf.Sin(45f * Mathf.Deg2Rad + thetaRad) - Mathf.Sin (45f * Mathf.Deg2Rad));                       
            float distanceZ = directionZ * radius * (Mathf.Cos (45f * Mathf.Deg2Rad) - Mathf.Cos (45f * Mathf.Deg2Rad + thetaRad));         
            transform.position = new Vector3(startPos.x + distanceX, startPos.y + distanceY, startPos.z + distanceZ);                       


            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRotation, toRotation,    ratio);      


            if (ratio == 1) {
                isRotate = false;
                directionX = 0;
                directionZ = 0;
                rotationTime = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you add a "monogame" tag? This seems to be purely about Unity

Comment: Also have you tried just adding kinematic rigidbodies (with is Kinematic set to true) to your objects?

Comment: Yes,just passes through the objects

Answer (score 0):

**if isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore. The rigidbody will be under full control of animation or script control by changing transform.position**

[Title Chart of collision on the bottom of this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)